# Scripting for SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This script works only in 2008 version:

```
declare @tab table(
id_emp int,
FIL_ROT_WID xml
)

insert into @tab
select 0, '<xml></xml>'

declare @xml_rot_widget xml
set @xml_rot_widget = '<ati id="1123" val="new()" />'

update @tab
set FIL_ROT_WID.modify('insert sql:variable("@xml_rot_widget")
                    as last
                    into (/xml)[1]')
where id_emp = 0

select * from @tab
```

In 2005 I receive the follow error:

```
XQuery: SQL type 'xml' is not supported in XQuery.
```

So, my question is:
How can I write code on 2008 (SQL Server Management Studio) that I will be sure that will works fine on 2005?

Ps.: ** Tools > Options > SQL Server Object Explorer > Scripting > Script for server version** does not work.

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Management studio is only a text editor with some intellisense. 
If you need your code to work in 2005, you need to connect to a 2005 box and run your tests on that.